How Do I Find Where a D365 Interface Is Located?
I'm trying to build a custom ExchangeRateProvider for D365 Finance & Operations based on this documentation.  When compiling I get errors because IExchangeRateProvider isn't referenced.
When working in .NET, I can usually google for a class or interface name and quickly find what assembly they are defined in, but this doesn't seem to be the case for D365.
How do I find out where a particular D365 element (class, interface etc) lives, if I don't yet have it referenced either as a model or .net reference.
Update 1: Things I've Tried

Application Explorer
Metadata Search

Unfortunately neither of these yielded any matches.
I found that the ECB exchange rate provider has an X++ wrapper class that implements this interface, which I was able to find in Application Explorer and see a copy of, which proves that the interface exists somewhere.

You can filter the Application Object Tree in the Application Explorer
by typing the name of the object (IExchangeRateProvider).

From there, you can check what model it belongs to.
Microsoft documentation: Filtering Application Explorer
